# How to make pages slug have priority over any category

Tags: urls, permissions

I use WordPress.

I need to show page instead of category when they have same slug.

- I have category called "Acne" with the slug "Acne"

  page and the category have the same slug.

When I write `www.example.com/acne` , the category page is opening,

I need to make WordPress to show the page instead of category when they have the same slug.

Is there any way to do that.

Comment: Asking for plugin recommendation is off-topic. [edit] and rewrite your question for actual cause.

Comment: I Am Trying To Make A Silo Structure Site With Wordpress.

Answer (score 2):

You can hook onto `parse_request` and trick WordPress into thinking it matched a page permalink if one exists with the same slug for a category term:

```
/**
 * Override query for pages that match a category slug.
 * 
 * @param   WP  $wp
 */ 
function wpse_177014_category_to_page ( $wp ) {
    if ( ! empty( $wp->query_vars['category_name'] ) && get_page_by_path( $slug = $wp->query_vars['category_name'] ) ) {
        if ( ! empty( $wp->query_vars['paged'] ) )
            $page = $wp->query_vars['paged'];
        else
            $page = '';

        $wp->matched_query = "pagename=$slug&page=$page";
        $wp->query_vars    = array(
            'pagename' => $slug,
            'page'     => $page,    
        );      
    }
}

add_action( 'parse_request', 'wpse_177014_category_to_page' );
```

Comment: Showing Page On Category Slug But Post Are Not Working..

In Post Url Like: http:/www.xxx.com/pageurl/posturl/

There Is Also Showing Page Contant

Comment: Anyone Can Correct This Script Or Can Give Any Other Script That Show page on category slug and post on post url?

Comment: Awesome solution - works perfectly for me.

Comment: This does work for pages, however the post under the category slug will return the page as well.